# Unable to start activity with the click of an image button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have made a custom theme for my action bar so that it displays three buttons on the top of the screen. With the click of the leftmost button, I want to start a new activity. However, I am unable to do so. I have used the correct method to start an activity and I am still getting an error. I don't know what the problem is.

The code I have written so far.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.contactmanager1;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ImageButton button1;
    private ImageButton button2;
    private ImageButton button3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false); 
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.button_layout);

        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_contact_listview);
        button1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        button2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_addcontact);
        button3= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_options);



        setUpListView();

    }

    private void setUpListView(){
        List <String> displayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        displayList.add("Display Item 1");
        displayList.add("Display Item 2");
        displayList.add("Display Item 3");


        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,displayList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        return true;
    }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        //Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_button_groups:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Groups.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void addContact(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddContact.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    public void groupPage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Groups.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

button_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/action_button_groups"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/groups"
                android:onClick="groupPage" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/contactlist" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/favourites" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

For the first image button in button_layout.xml I have added a onClick attribute to which points to the method groupPage. I have defined this method in MainActivity.java.

Comment: `I want to start a new activity. However, I am unable to do so.` - what are you getting after the button click ?

Comment: you dont have a listview in your layout. i test your code and removed code for action bar and list view. and it worked the activity started.

Comment: The layout in this question is the custom layout of the action bar. Not the main activity

Answer (score 0):

listView with a imagebutton causes problem as it consumes all touches to it.so try replacing the imagebutton with imageView or try this link.[try this link](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/)